# Underscore values from template not displaying in the $modal of angular ui bootstrap?

Tags: controller, scope, modal-dialog, underscore.js, angular-ui-bootstrap

I am new to angular I am trying to use the angular ui bootstrap $modal to show my template that has the underscore values but the modal does not render those values? Is there something wrong with the code? Please let me know I really need to fix this fast..The premiumprice (premiumdollar and premiumcents) value is not displayed in the modal..

HTML Code

```
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true" ng-click="cancel()">&times;</button>
                <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Confirm </h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <div class="modalBodyHead">
                    <h4>You are enrolling in</h4>
                    <h3>This Plan</h3>
                </div>
                <div class="planContent row">
                    <div class="col-md-12 col-xs-12 plans row">
                        <div class="planCard col-md-4 col-xs-4">
                            <div class="pBody">
                                <div ng-include src="'enroll.html'"></div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="planCard col-md-4 col-xs-4">
                            <div class="pBody">
                                <div ng-include src="'newenroll.html'"></div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="planCard col-md-4 col-xs-4">
                            <div class="pBody">
                                <div>This is out-of-Pocket section</div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <div class="col-md-4 col-xs-4 lAlign">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-link btnCancel" data-dismiss="modal" ng-click="cancel()">Cancel</button>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-8 col-xs-8">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-link btnNormal" data-dismiss="modal" ng-click="cancel()">Save and Return to Benefits</button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" data-dismiss="modal" ng-click="cancel()">Save and continue to dental</button>
                </div>
            </div>

</div>
```

The enroll.html template code

```
  <premium-view>
   <div class="planFeatCost">
                 <div class="premium row smallTxt clearfix">
                    <div class="col-md-7 col-xs-7 ">
                    </div>
                   <div class="col-md-5 col-xs-5">
               <div class="btn-group">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
                       <span class="caret"></span>
                   </button>
                   <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                       <li><a href="#">Month</a></li>
                   </ul>
               </div>
           </div>
       </div>

       <h3> ${{premiumDollars}} <sup>.{{ premiumCents }} </sup></h3>
              </div>
</premium-view>
```

The  controller js file having the $modal code

```
     angular.module('enrollment', ['ui.router.state'])

    .controller('ModalInstanceCtrl',['$scope','$modalInstance',function($scope,$modalInstance){
     $scope.cancel = function () {
     $modalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
      };

     }])
    .controller('confirmModalDialogController',['$scope','$modal','$location', 'WorkflowService', 'OptionPlusDependentService',function($scope,$modal,$location, WorkflowService, OptionPlusDependentService){

$scope.title ='Enrollment';

$scope.name = "HSA";

$scope.open = function () {

  var modalInstance = $modal.open({
    templateUrl: 'myModalContentEnroll.html',
    windowClass: 'modelT1',
    backdrop:  'static',
    keyboard: false,
    controller: 'ModalInstanceConfirmCtrl'

  });

   };
 }])
 .controller('ModalInstanceConfirmCtrl',['$scope','$modalInstance',function($scope,$modalInstance){
  $scope.cancel = function () {
  $modalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
  };

   }]);
```

The controller and directive calculating the premium price is in another js file

Comment: Could you put this all in a jsfiddle or plunkr. Otherwise it is a bit too tedious to look over. Also, the Premium price directive would be really helpful, since I understand the values for premiumdollar etc come from there?

Answer (score 0):

Although Im going on somewhat incomplete information (see my comment on question), I'm guessing the problem is actually quite simple:

```
ng-include src="'enroll.html'"
```

should just be replaced with

```
ng-include="'enroll.html'"
```

However - this might not be the only thing wrong.

Comment: Okay: I'll gladly take a deeper look, if you are willing to take 5 minutes to put all of this into a jsfiddle or plunkr. http://jsfiddle.net/joshdmiller/HB7LU/ is a nice template to work off of.